# Create fillable PDF form fields in existing PDF from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, forms, pdf

Is anyone aware of a way to create a fillable PDF form fields strict from code with NodeJS (or something that can be called from NodeJS)?

I am planning an application that takes an existing PDF an injects fillable form fields into marked sections resulting in a new PDF. This (second) PDF will be locked and released and then again filled from the database by filling only the form fields resulting in a third document.

Background is to create test documents from one database and later fill it from an other database in a regulated environment.

I found PDFFiller that is able to fill PDF forms but did not find any way to create form fields only by code.

Any tip or help is very appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I solved it by writing a java command line program using POI and PDFBOX that is called from node  and fed with the template and the data in JSON.